# "Sed" command to delete a line with exact matching string, no special characters to be included

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to delete a line from below file

```
localhost
localhost23
localhost-2.com
localhost-loopback.com
localhost.utopiad.com
localhostr.com
```

using `sed '/^localhost\b/d' file`

I don't understand why only the two lines `localhostr.com` and `localhost23` are printed. I want only the `localhost` line to be deleted...

Comment: Dash is not a word character.

Comment: yes, I understand. I only want the first line to be deleted ignoring the "-" or "." or any further character in the boundary

Comment: @steeldriver that comment of yours is the answer.

Comment: @ArjunCh please consider accepting [ikkachu's answer below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451768/65304)

Answer (score 5):

`\b` matches a word boundary in GNU sed, i.e. the point between a "word character" and a non-word character. Letters,  digits and underscores are the former, dots and dashes (among others) the latter, so there's a word boundary at the end of `localhost` at end of line, as well before the dots and dashes. But not between `t` and `2`, or `t` and `r`.

If you want to remove the line with the word `localhost` only, just use `sed -e '/^localhost$/d'`, or even `grep -vFx 'localhost'` (`-v` for inverted match, `-F` for fixed string match, `-x` for full line match).

Or, if you may have trailing whitespace: `sed -e '/^localhost[[:blank:]]*$/d'`

Comment: shoud i add `-i` to write it into same file?